# How to set the calendar of a Datepicker to be visible at all times, but also to be able to take the selected date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datepicker

This is my code.At this time the calendar appears only if i press the TextBox. I tried to put datepicker in < div > , but then I can not take the selected date.

```
@model Plotting.Models.CalendarModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calendar", "Home"))
{
    <p>   
        Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDate, new { @id = "txtdatepicker", @style = "width:200px;" })
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    if (ViewBag.Date != null)
    {
        <p>
            Your Selected Date :@ViewBag.Date
        </p>
    }
}
< script > 
    $(function () {
            $("#txtdatepicker").datepicker();
        }); 
< / script >
```

And here is the controller code :

```
          public ActionResult Calendar()
         {
             CalendarModel objdatemodel = new CalendarModel();
             objdatemodel.SelectedDate = "";
             return View(objdatemodel);
         }

         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Calendar(CalendarModel objdatemodel)
         {
             ViewBag.Date = objdatemodel.SelectedDate;
             return View(objdatemodel);
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put datepicker in a `div` and give it `altField` option to update your input. I think this is the simplest solution. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/kn3f208j/

HTML:

```
<input type='text' id='selectedDate'>
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        altField:"#selectedDate"
    });
});
```

**EDIT:**

Applying it on your example:

```
@model Plotting.Models.CalendarModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Calendar", "Home"))
{
    <p>   
        Date: @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SelectedDate, new { @id = "selectedDate", @style = "width:200px;" })
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    if (ViewBag.Date != null)
    {
        <p>
            Your Selected Date :@ViewBag.Date
        </p>
    }
}
< script > 
    $(function () {
            $("#datepicker").datepicker({
                altField:"#selectedDate"
            });
        }); 
< / script >
```